# Which pronoun should I use in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

Let's say I am talking to a person named Mike about another person David. Now if I want to tell Mike to talk to David only about a issue, then should I say:

> Please speak to David **himself** about that.
> or
> Please speak to David **itself** about that.

Which one is more appropriate??

Comment: There are other questions about "it" referring to a person: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56567/is-it-appropriate-to-refer-to-a-person-of-unknown-sex-by-it (I guess it's a separate question because it could be a different rule for *it* and *itself*, but it's not.)

Comment: Note that in normal speech, you would use neither.  You would say "Please speak to David about that."  Using "David himself" is *highly* marked.  It suggests that taling to David is normally impossible - for example if he is the King and so doesn't normally talk to Mike.

Comment: Downvoters: please leave a comment along with your downvote, or flag the question for closure if the problem is that bad

Answer (score 4):

Since David is a male (he), so we should use *himself* instead of *itself*. *Itself* can be used if you are talking about a thing. For example:

> The wound healed itself quickly.
>
> The picture itself rendered her speechless.

| subject pronoun | reflexive pronoun |
| --- | --- |
| I | myself |
| you (singular) | yourself |
| he | himself |
| she | herself |
| it | itself |
| one | oneself |
| we | ourselves |
| you (plural) | yourselves |
| they | themselves |

## Attribution

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns-reflexive-myself-themselves-etc

Answer (score 0):

correct: **himself**

'Himself' refers to David.

'Itself' can refer to a thing, an animal, a baby etc.

the cat itself, the television itself

We can use a reflexive pronoun together with the noun it refers to. (for emphasis)

We talked to the **teacher herself**

Reflexive pronouns: myself, **himself**, herself, itself, yourself, ourselves, themselves, yourselves

Comment: I've removed the maths characters that you were using for bold letters.